# How to maintain vue data changing url

Tags: vue.js

I made a component using Vuejs and there is a data.
And this currentPage value is being changed by click button.
For example, curretPage value is 3 by clicking button.

```
data(){
   return{
      currentPage: 1
   }
{
```

And I go to a specific url like "/order". After it, I come back to previous url where it has currentPage data.
But I want to maintain this currentPage as 3 not 1 after coming back.
But when I go to another url like "/hope", and come back, I expect the currentPage is 1 like default.
How can I control this using vuejs? Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one array in store with your values like

```
urls: [{home: 1}, {details: 2}]
```

and when url changes just fetch values from store related to your current url

Answer (score 0):

You can use somethings like s

```html
<script>
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return{
      currentPage: 1
    }
  },
  created() {
    const currentPage = localStorage.getItem('currentPage')
    if (currentPage > 0) {
      this.currentPage = currentPage
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setCurrentPage(value) {
      this.currentPage = value
      localStorage.setItem('currentPage', value)
    }
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```